# Multilingual support for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request, languages, english, cross-posting

Why is Stack Overflow branching off sites geographically/nationally?

Knowledge should be amalgamated, not categorized by country.
It doesn't make sense that the same question/answer exists on different sites created by Stack Overflow. How is this different to cross-posting?

It would be great if those that don't speak English can write an answer in their own language, and before the answer is shown to the public, it is translated and the translator receives some reputation points, similar to editing.

This feature could:

- Promote contribution overall
- Increase diversity
- Strengthen authority of Stack Overflow on computing matters

Comment: How would "those that don't speak English" be able to understand English questions in the first place, to then provide a high-quality non-English answer? And there are tons of problems with translation of an answer, first of all maintenance - if the translator is supposed to maintain the translated post, they have to understand it technically (meaning they could probably just write their own answer instead), if the original author should maintain it you would now have to translate comments for them, and figure out how they would edit their post which is no longer in a language they speak.

Comment: The original author of the post wouldn't be able to answer questions about the post, either.

Comment: [Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/)

Comment: @m0sa I see this idea has already been thrown around for a couple of years now...

Comment: It is a big world out there.  Big enough to let people speak different languages and to have questions typed in those languages.  Only 1.2 billion of them know English, a mere 17%.  The other 83% are a business opportunity :)

Answer (score 13):

> Why is SO branching off sites geographically/nationally?

We aren't. Those are by **language**, not geography nor nationality.

> How is this different to Cross-posting?

I can't read Russian. Or Japanese. And with my smattering of Portuguese, I can't figure out technical discussions in that language at all. The same question in a different language is just about non existent as far as I am concerned. This is not the same as the same question in the same language posted in a bunch of different sites (some of which are more suitable to it than others).

> It would be great if those that don't speak English can write an answer in their own language, and before the answer is shown to the public, it is translated

And how are they to *read* and understand the answer?

How are they to respond to comments?

How many languages are to be supported in such a manner?

---

Much better to give people a resource they can use natively.

Comment: How do Non-English speaking developers write code? Most of the time they can read English quite well, It's the writing part which is difficult. I work in Korea and find that the people use SO everyday, but I feel that they would contribute if only the language barrier didn't feel so high.

Comment: @Han but the language barrier _is_ high. You don't solve it by simply allowing other languages and saying "somebody can surely translate that". That would only lead to chaos, not to higher quality answers.

Comment: @Han - Knowing a few keywords and what they mean does **not** mean someone can read English well. And you feel that "they would contribute if only the language barrier didn't feel so high" - that's **why** SO in other languages exists - so people who are not comfortable writing in English can contribute.

Comment: Poor answer. Starts by fronting strawman right away -- despite the fact that it's rather obvious the question concerns language, not where your're residing -- by stating the obvious and the irrelevant, in bold font, no less. Continues by giving one self as an example, on meta site, no less. Oded, what should it matter for the site that _you_ can't speak Portuguese, Russian or Japanese? Do you sit on useful statistics claiming these people don't visit www.stackoverflow.com? No. Then your second point is nearly useless. If you can't read what's written, skip it -- others will step in.